# Does system encryption encrypt /home if it is on a separate HDD?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, hard-drive, encryption, ssd

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233077/full-disk-encryption-separate-home-partition) is similar but it seems to deal with a /home partition on same drive as / partition so not sure if answer would be the same as setup I am proposing.

I am hoping to set up my new laptop with / on a ssd and /home on a hdd. Ubuntu will be the only OS installed.
I was just planning to use the system encryption in the installation process.

I note that in the answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314005/why-am-i-given-the-option-to-also-encrypt-my-home-folder-after-ive-selected-sys) it is stated that

> With LUKS your entire installation (except /boot) will be encrypted, including your home directory.

I was not planning to use the separate /home encryption as I'll be the only user on the computer.

So if I select the LUKS encryption will this encrypt my /home partition on the separate hdd or do I need to customise my install in some way to accommodate this?

Comment: Have a look at this mailing list discussion: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2014-February/014828.html